# Make custom Error validation rule

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to store student info in database `id, name` with `course_1, course_2` from a form.
Same student can't register for same course again.

```
Students Table
id name
 1  X
 2  Y
Courses Table
 id course_name
 1   A
 2   B

Student_courses Table
 student_id courses_id
  1          1
  2          1
  2          2
```

Student controller like this :

```
public function studentRegistration(Request $request)
{
  $student = new Student();
  $student->name = $request->Input(['student_name']);
  $student->save(); 

   $courses = array(
            $request->Input(['course_1']),
            $request->Input(['course_2']), 
            $request->Input(['course_3'])
        );

   foreach ($courses as $course) 
        {
           $studentCourse = new StudentCourse();
           $studentCourse->student_id = $student->id;
           $studentCourse->course_id = $course;
           $studentCourse->save();
        }
}
```

How to make this custom validation with Laravel so same student can't take same course again?

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/custom-validation-rule-objects

Comment: you can also try it, in your sql database create unique index make student_id and course_id unique

Answer (score 0):

Could you use an existing rule?

Validation rules:

```
'course_1' => 'different:course_2,course_3|...',
'course_2' => 'different:course_3|...',
```

I am not sure how exact the actual problem is to the example. If these fields are more dynamic than that, then a custom rule would make sense.

That is just for validating the input to be unique values for those fields. To check against the database is where the `unique` rule can come in:

```
'course_1' => [..., $uniqueRule = Rule::unique('student_courses', 'course_id')->where('student_id', $whoEverTheStudentToCheckAgainstIs)],
'course_2' => [..., $uniqueRule],
'course_3' => [$uniqueRule],
```

Could hide that behind a custom rule if you really needed to.

Comment: but they are in other table.Means the course id with student id in different table?

Comment: That unique rule check would only allow students to sign up for one class.

Comment: forgot the column for unique ... it would say that a student could not sign up for the particular course a second time because `course_id` and `student_id` as a pair would be checked in the pivot or at least try to